# Has Pillai conjecture been proven?

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems, conjectures

I found the paper https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00698687v9/document which claims the proof of Pillai conjecture.

However, it is not mentioned anywhere that it has been proved. It's stated still as an open problem (hence: the conjecture, not theorem).

My question is: **Has Pillai conjecture been proven?**

[image]

The picture is from the book *Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat’s Last Theorem by Stewart and Tall.*

Comment: This is not a proof, this is gibberish. Take this sentence: "We will define Pillai numbers : we note them: $b_a$ they depend of $a$ and heve the same proprieties than $b$ for $a= 1$." What does this even mean?

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks for pointing it out. So, what are the best-known results currently?
There is a page on OEIS (https://oeis.org/A074981), a paper by Prof M. Waldschmidt (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.4031.pdf)  and a paper by Prof Michael A. Bennett (https://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/B-Pillai.pdf).
Where I can I find more result (the recent ones) on Pillai conjecture?

Comment: As, it has been pointed out in the comment, that the given paper is nothing but gibberish. I would like to know whether techniques used in the proof of Catalan conjecture by Prof Preda Mihăilescu (Pillai conjecture with $c=1$) can be applied to other values of $c$ or not? If yes, for which values?

Comment: For fixed $m,n,c$ you can prove finiteness using Baker's bound, which in principle can also be used to find all the solutions. If you let $m,n$ vary, then for $c>1$ Mihailescu's methods do not work - they rely too much on the properties of polynomials $x^k-1$ (they factor into cyclotomics, and the extensions their roots generate are abelian, and for no other $c$ in place of $1$ is it true for all $k$).

Answer (score 3):

guess I will throw this in. For a specific triple of numbers, two primes $p,q$ and then a target $n, \; \; $ [a youngster in Korea came up with a calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551324/exponential-diophantine-equation-7y-2-3x/1551383#1551383) that can often serve to prove the set of $p^a - q^b = n$ finite while identifying the largest $a,b$ that work. Maybe I will show the proof of the largest solution to 
$$ 7^a - 3^b = 100 $$

We  suspect that the largest solution is $343 = 243 + 100.$ Well, take $7^a - 343 = 3^b - 243.$ This becomes
$$ 343 ( 7^x - 1) = 243 ( 3^y - 1).  $$ We are going to prove that we cannot accomplish this with $x,y \geq 1.$

Assuming $x,y \geq 1:$
Since $$ 7^x \equiv 1 \pmod {243},  $$ we find $$ 81 | x \Longrightarrow 27 | x.  $$

$$  7^{27} - 1    = 2   \cdot 3^4   \cdot 19   \cdot 37   \cdot 109  \cdot  811  \cdot  1063   \cdot  2377  \cdot   2583253    $$
This divides $7^x - 1.$ In particular, $811 | (7^x - 1),$ and so $811 | (3^y - 1.)$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./order 3 811
811   810 = 2 * 3^4 * 5
```

$$  3^y \equiv 1 \pmod {811} \Longrightarrow 810 | y \Longrightarrow 81 | y. $$

$$  3^{81} - 1    = 2 \cdot    13 \cdot    109 \cdot    433  \cdot  757 \cdot    3889  \cdot  8209  \cdot \mbox{BIG} $$
In particular, $3^{81} - 1$ is divisible by $3889,$ so $3^y - 1$ is divisible by $3889.$ In turn, this means that $7^x - 1$ is divisible by $3889.$

$$  7^x \equiv 1 \pmod {3889} \Longrightarrow 1944 | x  \Longrightarrow 243 | x. $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./order 7 3889
3889  1944 = 2^3 * 3^5
```

We have shown $243 | x.$ However,
$$  7^{243} -1 =  2   \cdot 3^6   \cdot 19  \cdot 37   \cdot \mbox{Many More}$$
This means that
$$ 729 | (7^x - 1)  $$
This contradicts
$$ 343 ( 7^x - 1) = 243 ( 3^y - 1)  $$  with $x,y \geq 1.$

Comment: I followed each step of your proof, but I have no idea how you guessed the particular succession of divisors of the orders of $3$ and $7$ modulo something that would eventually lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen sorry. I wrote three computer programs. By the time I got to this problem, I was pretty confident about what i was looking for. However, as you suspect, I did not predict those primes by hand, I did a few computer searches.

Comment: So in fact it is essentially about finding $n$'s which are powers of 3 or 7 such that $ 7^n-1$ has a high 3-valuation or $ 3^n-1$ has a high 7-valuation, correct?